# LinkedIn Share API returns 400 error - "Owner entity type person is not supported"

Tags: share, linkedin-api

I am using the below body to hit the LinkedIn Share API endpoint. Unable to figure out what exactly is the reason for this error and no mention of this in the documentation.

POST REQUEST:

```
{
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [
            {
                "entityLocation": "https://www.sample.com",
                "thumbnails": [
                    {
                        "resolvedUrl": "https://www.sample.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "title": "Test Share with Content"
    },
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "owner": "urn:li:person:_EELFb0y",
    "subject": "Test Share Subject",
    "text": {
        "text": "Test Share!"
    }
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "message": "Owner entity type person is not supported",
    "status": 400
}
```

---

Any help on this?

Comment: Have you found another solution? facing same problem and below suggest tion does not work. See comment below.

Answer (score 0):

[Official LinkedIn API DOCS]

In v2 API, LinkedIn uses "author", not "owner"

```
{
"author": "urn:li:person:8675309",
"lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
"specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
        "shareCommentary": {
            "text": "Hello World! This is my first Share on LinkedIn!"
        },
        "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
    }
},
"visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
}
```

}

May be that is the reason for that status=400

Comment: Nice idea with author but it does not work. It returns the error ```{'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'message': 'Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]', 'status': 403}``` LinkedIn's official documentation at the time of this comment said to specify it ```owners={URN}``` [link documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http#find-shares-by-owner)